# How can i create a Linux Script (bash, sed, awk...) to add a line in a specific section of a configuration's file

Tags: bash, sed

I need make a script with Linux common tools (Bash, awk, sed,...) to edit a configuration file in a style like INI, that is:

```
[sectionA]
var1=x
var2=y
#...

[sectionB]
var1=x
var2=y
#...

[sectionC]
var1=x
var2=y
#...
```

I need add a line in a specific section, that is, find a part that start with a line "[sectionX]" and append a line BEFORE the next new line or EOF. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -i '/^\[sectionB\]/a\append your line here' my_file
```

or

```
sed -i '/^\[sectionB\]/s/$/\nappend your line here/' my_file
```

example appending a line to `[sectionB]` using either command line above

the output

```
[sectionA]
var1=x
var2=y
#...

[sectionB]
append your line here
var1=x
var2=y
#...

[sectionC]
var1=x
var2=y
#...
```

Comment: Assuming section exist

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/\(\[sectionB\]\)/\1\nvar_new=value/' -i file.ini
```

Note that if `file.ini` already has a line defining `var_new=something_else` you will need to remove it separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `gnu awk`

```
awk -vRS= -vORS="\n\n" -F"\n" -vOFS="\n" '/sectionB/ {$1=$1"\nnew=42"}1' file
[sectionA]
var1=x
var2=y
#...

[sectionB]
new=42
var1=x
var2=y
#...

[sectionC]
var1=x
var2=y
#...
```

Search for `sectionB` then add `new=42` in that section.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [crudini](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programs/crudini) to edit the file more robustly/easily

```
crudini --set file 'sectionB' new 42
```